# using linked list in another linkedlist in fortran

Tags: linked-list, fortran

I have a List(A) which consists of three node A1, A2, A3. Every node in list A has own node B1, B2, B3. In other words node A1 has a list of nodes(B1,B2,B3), node A2 has own list(B1,B2,B3).....
How can I implement it in Fortran.

I write two modules for it.

```
MODULE B
TYPE NODE_B 
 INTEGER :: i
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(:) :: INPUT
 TYPE(NODE_B) , POINTER :: NEXT_B
END TYPE NODE_B
......
......
END MODULE B


The second Module 
MODULE A
TYPE NODE_A 
INTEGER ::j
TYPE(NODE_B) :: INPUT_A
TYPE(NODE_A), POINTER :: NEXT_A
END NODE_A
.....
.....
END MODULE A
```

I am not sure about TYPE NODE_A.

Comment: From your description you seem to have a 3-way tree rather than a linked list.  What (code) have you got so far ?

Comment: I want to write it in Fortran.

Comment: Do you need a hierarchical tree or a flat array (Nx3)?

Comment: Did you study the document @Fraser recommended in a comment on your earlier, very similar, question ?  A careful study of that would lead you towards the knowledge you seek.